# Implementing x-editable to each single field + select get data onload/update

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, x-editable

For a long time I am trying to make a x-editable datatable. I want to edit all fields, the examples were only show for only editing fields :

```
x1
x2
x3
```

and not the other one.

Here is the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/3485/

Im also wondering how to setup the select to get the data and then how to update them ( first probably is a onload function? and second a ajax update.php if im right. ) but apart from this I get errors on the data.php file while I wan't to update the bywho field. Really thanks in investigating this annoying case. Looking forward tips.

**data.php**

```
//delay (for debug only)
sleep(1); 
require_once("../checklogin.php");
require_once("../lib/functions.php");
require_once("../lib/Db.class.php");

// Creates the instance  || preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,12}$/', $_POST['password'])
$db = new Db();
$user = new users();
$error = array();

/*
You will get 'pk', 'name' and 'value' in $_POST array.
*/
$pk = $_REQUIRE['pk'];
$name = $_REQUIRE['name'];
$value = $_REQUIRE['value'];
/*
 Check submitted value
*/
if(!empty($value)) {
    /*
      If value is correct you process it (for example, save to db).
      In case of success your script should not return anything, standard HTTP response '200 OK' is enough.

      for example:
      $result = mysql_query('update users set '.mysql_escape_string($name).'="'.mysql_escape_string($value).'" where user_id = "'.mysql_escape_string($pk).'"');
    */
    $update = $db->query("UPDATE tbl_ticket SET ".$name." = :fvalue WHERE id = :id", array(
        "fvalue" => $value,
        "id" => $pk
    ));
    //here, for debug reason we just return dump of $_POST, you will see result in browser console
    echo "ok";
} else {
    /* 
    In case of incorrect value or error you should return HTTP status != 200. 
    Response body will be shown as error message in editable form.
    */

    header('HTTP 400 Bad Request', true, 400);

}
```

**Debug of data.php: on change input bywho**

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: _REQUIRE in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\platform\admin\data.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: _REQUIRE in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\platform\admin\data.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: _REQUIRE in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\platform\admin\data.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
```

**My function to draw the data**

```
function drawticket()
    {
        global $db;
        $drawUserstb = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket");

        foreach ($drawUserstb as &$rows) {
            echo '<tr>  
                    <td>'.$rows['id'].'</td>  
                    <td class="edit bywho '.$rows['id'].'"><a href="#" id="bywho" data-type="text" data-title="Bywho Id" data-pk= "'.$rows['id'].'" data-value="'.$rows['bywho'].'">'.$rows['bywho'].'</a></td>  
                    <td class="edit message '.$rows['id'].'">'.$rows['message'].'</td>  
                    <td class="edit prority '.$rows['id'].'">
                    <a href="#" id="prority" data-title="Prority" data-type="select" data-pk= "'.$rows['id'].'" data-value="'.$rows['prority'].'" data-param="XXX">'.$rows['prority'].'</a>
                    </td>  
            </tr>';
        }
    }
```

**Script that runs the edit actions**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('td.edit a').editable({
        type: 'text',
        url: 'data.php',      
        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'put'
        }        
    });
    $('.td.e

dit a[id=prority]').editable({
     loadurl : 'include/json.php',
     submit : 'OK'
});

//ajax emulation
$.mockjax({
    url: '/post',
    responseTime: 200,
    response: function(settings) {
        console.log(settings);
    }
}); 

});
```

**Json for select edit ( temporary setup )**

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require_once("../../../checklogin.php");
    require_once("../../../lib/functions.php");
    require_once("../../../lib/Db.class.php");

    $db = new Db();
    $user = new users();
    $error = array();
 $array['1'] =  'No prority'; 
 $array['2'] =  'Important'; 
 $array['0'] =  'V important'; 
 $array['selected'] =  '1';
 print json_encode($array);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm following your questions completely.

I believe in the first part you're saying you want all the fields in the table to be editable?

Assuming that's the case it looks like theres some problems with your selectors.  The selector "td.edit a" is selecting all  elements under a  element with class edit.  This one is actually selecting both the "bywho" column and the "proraty" column. Its not selecting the elements in the message column because there isn't an anchor tag there (ie ).

The selector '.td.edit a[id=prority]' isn't actually selecting anything because of the . before the td.  The . means class. so its trying to find elements with a class "td" and a class "edit" of which there are none in your document.  If you remove the . it will select the anchor tag in the "proraty" column however its already selected by the above selector.

If you want all elements in the table to be editable you may want to instead do something like:

`$('td.edit').children().editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: 'data.php',

    ajaxOptions: {
        type: 'put'
    }

});`

Note that this requires there to be an element in each , not just text.  So you'd need to wrap superusers in a  tag.  http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/4230/

Also, in regards to the errors you're seeing in the php.  I think the error means that the variable you're using _REQUIRE is not defined.  I believe you should be using $_POST instead. (i.e. $pk = $_POST['pk'];)

In any case it seems like you're on the right track.